# Register DLL with 'regasm' from MSI

Tags: c#, dll, windows-installer

I want to create `msi` setup file for my DLL. Right now I'm registering my `.dll` using command line using following commands

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>regasm mydll.dll /codebase
```

I want to do same from my `.msi` file. How to achieve that in visual studio while creating `.msi` I'm creating this `.msi` in x64 machine.

FYI: I'm java developer so don't know much about `.net`

Comment: How are you building your msi file? Visual Studio setup project? Wix? InstallShield? Something else?

Comment: Visual Studio Setup Project

Comment: If you select the file to be registered in the File System Editor within the setup project, you should find a "Register" property in the properties grid where you can set various different flavours of COM registration. There shouldn't be any need to invoke `regasm`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get path of Framework in MSI custom actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504497/get-path-of-framework-in-msi-custom-actions)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried to tell him that in his last question.