# Get path of Framework in MSI custom actions

Tags: c#, dll, windows-installer

I'm trying to execute custom commands on my DLL using `.msi`. I want to know that How to get `x86` framework path(`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`) in `x64 machine` and `x86 machine`

[MSI Error - Failure of regsvr32 custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822223/msi-error-failure-of-regsvr32-custom-action)

To get system path use we use `[SystemFolder]` so is there any property to get location of `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`

[image]

related article

[Getting the .NET Framework directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375860/getting-the-net-framework-directory-path)

Comment: I attached image. Check that I want there. And FYI I'm java developer but have to work around .net so... Do I have to write function in my dll provided in above link? And how to call that function in custom actions..

Comment: What is the custom command you want to execute?

Comment: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727> regasm.exe mydll.dll /codebase

Comment: What tool are you using to author your MSI?

Answer (score 0):

"Self registration" (Regsvr32, Regasm, GACUTIL, InstallUtil et al) is not considered a best practice in Windows Installer because it runs out of process, isn't declarative and isn't transactional.  It defeats Windows Installers knowledge of the changes being made to the target machine, is slower, often fragile and often breaks in repair, upgrade, downgrade, rollback et al scenarios.

The alternative is to "harvest" or "extract" the COM metadata associated with your assembly and author them natively into your MSI.  How you do this exactly depends on what tool you are using to author your MSI.   InstallShield has a setting called ".NET Com Visible" and WiX has a feature called "Heat".  A more raw approach is to run the command  regasm foo.dll /regfile:out.reg and then author the contents of the regfile into your installer by hand substituting the paths with MSI directory properties.

There is one catch with regasm /regfile as documented on the [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) topic in MSDN:

> Note that the .reg file does not contain any registry updates that can
>   be made by user-defined register functions.